# Calling method from generic class

Tags: c#, generics, data-access-layer

I am building generic sharepoint DALL so i need a help here. 
I dont know if this is applicable , but it logically it must be.

My problem is my gr8 TTL is not sure what is the data source he need to use :S (SQL or SharePoint lists) and he need to start development for the project.

so i need to build DAL as SP lists is my datasource so the changing in future will be to the minimal.

Now what I have is baseDAL that includes all the common operations such delete,getAll,,,etc

myBase dal class now something like

```
public class BaseDAL<T> where T : BaseInfo,new()
{
    public virtual List<T> GetAllItem()
{
   //code to read from any data source and return data

}
public virtual Boolean Delete(T entity)
 {
    int entityID  = ((BaseInfo)entity).ID;
    deleteEntity(entityID);
 }
```

}

and i have baseInfo calss as main business object entity.

and lets say i have two business entities (employee, student) and two DAL one for employee and one for student

so what i am thinking is implementing code in getAllItem that returnes all items based on the T type, so the code maybe looks like bellow in baseDAL

```
public virtual List<T> GetAllItem()
{

   SPListItemCollection items = //code to read from list please note that list name saved in baseInfo object
   T.getBusinessListItems(items); //toList

}
```

and in EmployeeDAL I implements a mapper function between SPListItemCollection to business entities the code will be samiliare to this

```
public virtual List<Employee> getBusinessListItems(SPListItemCollection items)
{

  //loop the items and fill them in list of employee objects
  return list<Employee>

}
```

hope this clarify the case , i dont know if this is the write way to do it i am not pretty a   technical guy. if there is another way to do it please help.

Comment: i cant understand your problem..what do you want to do...

Comment: I've added a tag for C#, since i assume this is in C#. Please change it if this is not so.

Comment: specially the `T.toList` part!what are you trying to do here...

Comment: The question here is very unclear; also, this probably isn't a good use of generics unless the underlying data-source *also* supports generics (for example, LINQ-to-SQL has `GetTable<T>`). But for most examples I can think of: the implemetation would not be "generic", so *generics* are probably not the right technology choice for this. Finally, very rarely would the consumer be generic here.

Comment: If you are saying that you should have a static method such as `Student.toList()`, `Employee.toList()`, then again: I'd probably say that isn't a very good design approach *to begin with*. Generics does not have an inbuilt metaphor to execute static duck-typed methods. You could do it with reflection, but: yeuch.

Comment: Thanks marc , so in DAL i dont think its good to rewrite all the code again and again for each calss such as (EmployeeHanlder, Student Handler) what is the best approach for this case. I had edited the question hope its clear now. thanks again.

Comment: @BakriBasha The base cae is tio realize you are in a dead cornder - anti pattern, wasting Money. Why the heck do you think manually coding all those cases is better than a code Generator or the Standard, an IQueryable implementation? There should not even be a "GetAllitems" method to start with. Please learn waht C# offers you. Read about LINQ.

Comment: TomTom, first i said that i am not a technical and if there any other way i am ok to know about, i dont know what is IQueryable i will search about it if this will help me in this case , but what i am sure is ( dont use linq for sharepoint in case you have large amount of data transaction.) then i will back to same problem i dont want to write the same code in each class i use even if it was generated, and how long you think it will take for writing the mapped function 5-10 mints with test ?! thanks for your help any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but it might help:

```
object someDal = ...; //you don't know the exact type
var list = ((dynamic)someDal).GetAllItem();
```

C# dynamic already solves this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks man, but i think the actual implementation now need to be the EmployeeDAL , which this is what i need not to do. i need the implementation that get the data to be on the BaseDAL , and the baseDAL handel the converting to business types based on T.

Answer (score 0):

finally i managed to do it ,,
with the same structure i have i used the following code , i think its called reflection i am not sure ,,

```
public virtual List<T> GetAllItems(Type DalType)//this is baseDAL
{
  MethodInfo methodInfo = DalType.GetMethod("ConvertToBusinessEntities");
  object[] parametersArray = new object[] { itemCollection };
  object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(DalType, null);
  return (List<T>)methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
}
```

i am only need to pass the DalType to know which class to call the method from , the code will work if makes sure that all the DALs will implements ConvertToBusinessEntities method , which that i can manage by interface.
i hope this structure of code is strong enough... 
it was not dead end after all :) ,,,